# How to Show Days Month or Year with date_diff in PHP

Tags: php, diff

I want the system to show **Days** if the value is **<30 Days**.

but When the value **>30 Days** it should show **1 Month** and when number of Months are **>12 Months**,

then system should show **1 Year**.

for example when the output is 1 days 5 months 0 years

so i want the system just show me `5 months` i don't want to show **days** and **year**

here is the basic code using diff

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("now");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%d days %m months %y years");
```

output is `11 days 1 months 5 years`.

As this is showing **Years** i want the system to hide **Day** and **Month** and only show **Year**.

so, the output must be like This `5 years`.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this

Comment: `echo $diff->format("%y years");` thats it

Comment: haha, this one is manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a simple `if-else` condition to check that year, month, days are greater than 0 or not, and based on that show any-one of them.

Do like below:-

```
if($diff->y > 0){
  echo $diff->format("%y years");
}else if($diff->m > 0){
  echo $diff->format("%m months");
}else if($diff->d > 0){
  echo $diff->format("%d days");
}else { 
  echo "Today"; 
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/994989

Comment: @Jazuly  glad to help you :):)